# density plot, color and facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

\edit I uploaded the matframe as a txt [here](https://expirebox.com/files/0b1afca0eb2c75a61db8497ddcbab367.txt). Open with notepad++ (each 1e3 in dist is a 1000)

I have a dataframe that looks similiar to this:

```
    variable value  dist column row avg
    x1       2      1000 1      1   2
    x2       2.3    1000 2      1   2.3
    x3       2.7    1000 1      2   2.7
    x4       2.4    1000 2      2   2.4
    x1       2.1    500  1      1   2.1
    x2       2.3    500  2      1   2.3
    x3       2.4    500  1      2   2.4
    x4       2.3    500  2      2   2.3
```

this is the code, that I have so far:

```
   p11<- ggplot(df, aes(x=value, fill=as.factor(df$dist))) + 
  geom_density()+ 
  facet_grid(row ~ column)
```

My goal is a density plot that has a facet grid by row and column. Each plot for a specific row and column should have one plot for dist 500 and another for dist 1000. On top of that a vertical line should be printed for the avg var at dist=500 and dist=1000. But my plot looks like this

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it.

Code:

```
# Load the packages
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)

# Load the data
df = read.table("mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", dec = ".")

# recode variable as factor
df$dist = as.factor(df$dist)
df$col = as.factor(df$col)
df$row = as.factor(df$row)

# add the log of the numeric variables "val" and "avg" for better plotting scales
df$log_val = log(df$val)
df$log_avg = log(df$avg)

# Plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log_val)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..density.., fill = dist), adjust = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = log_avg, color = dist), size = 1, linetype = "dashed")+
  facet_grid(col ~ row, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

Results:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Oh my god. I don't know to thank you for this. I've been sitting here for half a day trying to figure out how I can accomplish that. A thousand thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome, I have been there many times myself, but the stackoverflow community has rescued me many times :D
Best of luck!